# Is it possible to ensure object completeness and keep properties types?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to write type `AllValidators`, so that it ensures that object of its type has `ALL` keys from `ValidatorName` AND each property keeps its original type?

So that const `validator` on the bottom stays of type `Validator<string>`.

(I **don't want** `validator` to be `any`, `Validator<any>`, `Validator<string|number|boolean>`)

Thanks!

```
type ValidatorName = 'maxLength' | 'required' | 'regexp';

type Validator<P> = {
  (value: string, param: P): boolean;
};

type AllValidators = {
  [key in ValidatorName]: ???
}

const allValidators: AllValidators = {
  maxLength: ((value: string, param: number) => false) as Validator<number>,
  required: ((value: string, param: boolean) => false) as Validator<boolean>,
  regexp: ((value: string, param: string) => false) as Validator<string>,
}

const validator = allValidators.regexp
```

Comment: My question is why is `maxLength` of type `Validator<number>` and `required` of type `Validator<boolean>`. This paring is not in any of the types you list in your question. If we were to create such a map type (something like `{ maxLength: number, required: boolean }`) then writing the mapped type would e trivial, but without this information conceptually there is no way to do it.

Comment: In my case I have individual validators in separate files.
Then I am combining them to one `allValidators` object and then infering a "Rules" type from it which is  `{ maxLength: number, required: boolean, regexp: string }`
My question is, how to ensure the completeness of this `allValidators` object, so that I don't forgot to update this allValidators when a new Validator is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a variable that is both constrained to an interface and have its type inferred based on the assigned value. You can instead use a function, with a type parameter. The type parameter can have a constraint but the actual type of the parameter will captured from the call.

```
type ValidatorName = 'maxLength' | 'required' | 'regexp';

type Validator<P> = {
    (value: string, param: P): boolean;
};

function createAllValidators<T extends { [P in ValidatorName]: Validator<any> }>(o: T) {
    return o;
}
const allValidators = createAllValidators({
    maxLength: ((value: string, param: number) => false),
    required: ((value: string, param: boolean) => false),
    regexp: ((value: string, param: string) => false),
})

const validator = allValidators.regexp

// { maxLength: number; required: boolean; regexp: string; }
type Rules = {
    [P in keyof typeof allValidators] : (typeof allValidators[P] extends Validator<infer T>? T: never)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's quite simple if you reverse the logic and type in places and use `typeof` to simply catch the type of `allValidators`:

```
type Validator<P> = {
  (value: string, param: P): boolean;
};

const allValidators = {
  maxLength: ((value: string, param: number) => false) as Validator<number>,
  required: ((value: string, param: boolean) => false) as Validator<boolean>,
  regexp: ((value: string, param: string) => false) as Validator<string>,
}

type AllValidators = typeof allValidators;

const validator = allValidators.regexp
```

You don't even need `ValidatorName` anymore (and it is arguable whether you need `AllValidators` at all as well).

Comment: Good catch, I might reverse the logic as you say and just:

`type ValidatorName = keyof typeof allValidators;`